# Add suffix to a decimal row (to show litres)

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms, suffix

I'm using Eureka Forms for swift 2 and I'm trying to add a Suffix to a DecimalRow. My the reason is that in this row the user will enter the amount of litre consumed, so I would like the row to display the L at the end all the time

I did not find anything in the API docs to help me with this....

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: Idid not no, this project is on ice for now so I don't look for a solution right now, but if you find any it would be very appreciated and helpful